# ASP.NET Web API - Authetication in Windows Forms Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I developed a web system using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I must perform an integration using .NET Web API and Windows Forms Application.

So far everything has been fine, but now I need to authenticate the users using Windows Forms Application and this application will be open on the internet.

My application already contains users that are registered in the database and currently are authenticated using the component 'Authorize' of ASP.NET MVC.

For data consumption through the client (Windows Forms Application) currently I use the library Microsoft ASP.NET Web Client API.

How can I accomplish this task safely?
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How is your Windows Forms application calling your WebApi?

Comment: For data consumption through the client (Windows Forms Application) currently I use the library Microsoft ASP.NET Web Client API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the HttpClient to add authentication. One example can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/extending-httpclient-with-oauth-to-access-twitter.aspx). It shows how to add a `HttpMessageHandler` into your pipeline for authentication using OAuth.

Here is the complete [List of ASP.NET Web API and HttpClient Samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/26/asp-net-web-api-and-httpclient-samples.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629530/how-to-customize-asp-net-web-api-authorizeattribute-for-unusual-requirements) which describes creating a custom AuthorizeAttribute  for Web API that also authenticates the user using http basic security and grabbing the credentials from the HTTP header.  Note that there is a different AuthorizeAttribute for ASP.NET Web API (System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute) as opposed to the one for an MVC controller (System.Web.Mvc.AuthroizeAttribute). They have different behaviors. You do not want a call to a Web API being redirected to a logon page.