# ASP.NET MVC 5 Handle Unauthorize Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement access denied error page on a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Individual User Accounts Authentication Mode.
I add `CustomAuthorize` class that inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected virtual CustomPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles))
            {
                if (!CurrentUser.IsInRole(Roles))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));

                    //base.OnAuthorization(filterContext); // returns to login url
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Users))
            {
                if (!Users.Contains(CurrentUser.UserName))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));

                    //base.OnAuthorization(filterContext); // returns to login url
                }
            }
        }
    }


    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
}
```

add `ErrorController.cs`

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and `AccessDenied.cshtml` view

```
<h2>Access Denied</h2>
<p>You do not have access to view this page</p>
```

then applied in `HomeController.cs`

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

but it always redirecting to login page. How to display the access denied page?

Comment: Does it redirect authenticated users to the login page as well?

Comment: @takemyoxygen Yes it does, but I need to redirect to AccessDenied page

Comment: I can confirm that nothing wrong with your CustomAuthorize  or Error controllers as I have tested this in a mvc 5 template with Individual User Accounts. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new mvc 5 project with Individual User Accounts, add your Error Controller, view and CustomAuthorize attribute class.

Then update home controller like below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [CustomAuthorize(Roles = "TestRole")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Register and login, try to click on the About link you'll get redirected to access denied page as there is no user with role 'TestRole'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `OnAuthorization` method on CustomAuthorize class. If this method exist it will never reach `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you have to handle it inside the OnAuthorization. And you may need to change status code to 401.

Comment: Could you show me how to handle inside `OnAuthorization`? and why it never reach `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`

Comment: It seems like OnAuthorization() and IsAuthorized() calls first and then calls HandleUnauthorizedRequest(), because of that we have to deal it that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629530/how-to-customize-asp-net-web-api-authorizeattribute-for-unusual-requirements