# Custom Authorization in Asp.net WebApi call only for authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented token based authentication.
I want to write custom authorize attribute.

The reason behind this is, sometime UserIdentity.GetUserId() gives null.

So to handle this I have written the custom authorize attribute, like the following.

This custom Authorize calls for all the calls (anonymous or authorize call).
So I have used the property IsAuthorizeCall to check whether the call is coming from anonymous or authorized.

**Can I make the calls like, I want to call this custom authorzie only when I mentioned above method. Otherwise this should not be called.**

**How can I do that?**

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public bool IsAuthorizeCall { get; set; }
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            if (IsAuthorizeCall)
            {
                IdentityHelper IdentityHelper = new IdentityHelper();
                if (IdentityHelper.UserId== Guid.Empty)
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }

}
```

**Referenced:**

[Custom Authorization in Asp.net WebApi - what a mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464848/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-webapi-what-a-mess)

[How to Customize ASP.NET Web API AuthorizeAttribute for Unusual Requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629530/how-to-customize-asp-net-web-api-authorizeattribute-for-unusual-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself.

> If add the filter to the global asax, then it will be called for all
>   the controllers and action even if mentioned or not.

So we need to remove the following from **global.asax**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorize());
```

So now, the custom athorize will be call only when mentioned in the controller or action.