# Working with a separate Identity Web API and authorize in another API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I currently have an asp.net Web API that uses identity authentication which an angular client then uses to authenticate users using an access token.

I want to have a another separate restful API that deals with the logic, crud operations etc side of things but I want this to have [Authorise] on the controllers to ensure it is secure.

[image]

What would be the best way to achieve this? Do I have to install identity on this logic API too?

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: What’s the authorization method? jWT or Basic?

Comment: Im currently getting an access_token from the identity api and using that to authenticate the user in a seperate angular 6 client, so basic setup i think

Comment: I think a separate Auth API will create overhead? But each case is different

Comment: The other API will be massively rowing so i was separating out the authentication so this could be maintained separately. Can you explain why this would create an overhead? Also, whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I could be wrong but that’s another layer of HTTP communications, so there’s  might be some overhead.

Comment: Maybe try customizing the `[Authorize]` attribute, and call the Auth API instead of doing the default authorizations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629530/how-to-customize-asp-net-web-api-authorizeattribute-for-unusual-requirements